# hide wait popup in oracle apex

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

I call an application process in my oracle apex page and displayed a wait popup before calling the application process using the code

```
apex.widget.waitPopup();
```

It works fine and then I want to remove the wait popup after the process is completed, so I used the code

```
$("#apex_wait_popup").remove();  
$("#apex_wait_overlay").remove();
```

But the remove code doesn't works. What might be the reason?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you're on Apex 5, Jorge Rimblas says [here](https://rimblas.com/blog/2015/08/enhancement-to-waitpopup-on-apex5/) that you should use the `remove()` function. Have a look, try it.

```
var $wP;

setTimeout(function(){
    $wP = apex.widget.waitPopup();
}, 10);

  // do long running "stuff"

$wP.remove();
```

Comment: yea. thanks. I didn't declared the variable $wP, when I tried this earlier. now it works. thank you.